# Setting the viewWindow min max in hours of a Google Chart in Razor

Tags: razor, charts, google-visualization

I have an Google chart with the following options for the hAxis. But I cannot get the viewWindow to work

This Razor code:

```
    hAxis: {
            format: 'HH:mm',
            showTextEvery: 2,
            gridlines: {
                count: -1,
                units: {hours: {format:['HH:mm']}}
            },
            viewWindow: {
                min: new Date(@Model.SelectedDate.Year, @Model.SelectedDate.Month-1, @Model.SelectedDate.Day, 0),
                max: new Date(@Model.SelectedDate.Year, @Model.SelectedDate.Month-1, @Model.SelectedDate.Day, 23, 59)
            }
        },
```

Produces the following html

```
    hAxis:{
            format: 'HH:mm',
            showTextEvery: 2,
    viewWindow: {
                min: new Date(2017, 7-1, 6, 0),
                max: new Date(2017, 7-1, 6, 23, 59)
            },
            gridlines: {
                count: -1,
                units: {hours: {format:['HH:mm']}}
            },

        },
```

This code gives an error: getTime is not a function

How do I change the razor code so it will take my date in the javascript part for the chart.

When I remove the lines of the viewWindow part then my chart is working. So I don't think my Data is the problem.

And some of my data

```
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Tijdstip');
    data.addColumn('number', 'gemeten temperatuur');
        data.addRows([
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 0, 34), -16.56200000],
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 1, 38), -16.44000000],
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 2, 39), -16.27600000],
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 3, 44), -15.78500000],
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 4, 47), -15.74400000],
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 5, 52), -15.41700000],
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 6, 52), -15.17100000],
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 7, 57), -14.88500000],
                [new Date(2017, 2-1, 22, 0, 8, 58), -14.35300000],
```

tia Ronald

Answer (score 0):

the values used for `viewWindow` are valid, don't believe that is the problem

see following working snippet using the posted options...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 6, 1), 1000],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 6, 2), 2000],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 6, 3), 3000],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 6, 4), 4000],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 6, 5), 5000],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 6, 6), 6000]
  ]);


  var options = {
    hAxis:{
      format: 'HH:mm',
      showTextEvery: 2,
      viewWindow: {
        min: new Date(2017, 7-1, 6, 0),
        max: new Date(2017, 7-1, 6, 23, 59)
      },
      gridlines: {
        count: -1,
        units: {hours: {format:['HH:mm']}}
      },
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: i'm thinking the error occurs when building the data table, please share a sample of the data used to build the chart...